# How to add a map to your store on contact us page

Tags: magento

I want to add a location map of my address on contact us page. All I did was copy html from google map and paste it in the static block and call that static block in contact us page but it displayed nothing.

What am I missing or what should I do to get the very clear map of my store?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the tips,

Have you cleared the magento cache? If no, then clear them

Are you having a separate CMS page , if so then copy the google code in the content of that page instead of creating a static block and then call them in contact us page.

If u have done all, then make sure that you enabled the contact us page..

Anyway more info can help you to get the correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

Put your google maps iframe to form.phtml file this lines:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=hu&amp;geocode=&amp;q=IT-Droid,+Szigetszentmikl%C3%B3s,+T%C3%B6k%C3%B6li+%C3%BAt+8,+Magyarorsz%C3%A1g&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=it-dr&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=54.884801,110.302734&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=IT-Droid,&amp;hnear=2310+Szigetszentmikl%C3%B3s,+T%C3%B6k%C3%B6li+%C3%BAt+8,+Magyarorsz%C3%A1g&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=14069203674977933958&amp;ll=47.347203,19.044896&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=hu&amp;geocode=&amp;q=IT-Droid,+Szigetszentmikl%C3%B3s,+T%C3%B6k%C3%B6li+%C3%BAt+8,+Magyarorsz%C3%A1g&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=it-dr&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=54.884801,110.302734&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=IT-Droid,&amp;hnear=2310+Szigetszentmikl%C3%B3s,+T%C3%B6k%C3%B6li+%C3%BAt+8,+Magyarorsz%C3%A1g&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=14069203674977933958&amp;ll=47.347203,19.044896" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Nagyobb térképre váltás</a></small>
```

(like app\design\frontend\base\default\template\contacts\form.phtml) under

```
<h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just successfully input a google map on my contact page. instead of using a static block, you should use a cms page. just paste the code from google map in the content area under the show editor view, and enable it. that should do the trick. hope it works for you. cheers.